# child records and ember model

Tags: ember.js, firebase, ember-model

#### [Update]

Thanks for the help so far.

I've been able to create a new Post record with an embedded Comment record with static data.  Via this method:

```
    App.CommentsController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
      needs: "post",
      
      actions: {

         addComment: function() {
              var post = App.Post.create({
                title: 'static post'
              });

                  post.get('comments').create({
                    message: 'static message'
                });
                  
                  post.save();

          }

      }

    });
```

But I'm falling short figuring out how to retrieve the current Post via the CommentsController or Route in order to create Comment records on an already existing Post.

After searching and sifting through random SOs and articles, I've tried an array of methods to call the current Post but still no dice.

I've tried setting `var post = App.Post.create` to:

```
var post = App.Post.find(), 
var post = this.get('controllers.post.model'),
var post = this.get('controllers.post.content'),
var post = this.get('controllers.post'),
var post = this.get('post'),
```

I've also set my `CommentsController` to have `needs: "post"`.

I've also tried adding:

```
    App.CommentsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
        afterModel: function() {
            this.set('post', this.modelFor('post'));
        }
    });
```

I read a piece that stated actions should be defined in the routes as well, would I need to define my `addComment` function in the `PostRoute`?

I'm wondering if I need to use `var post = App.Post.find(post)` or something of that nature.

Am I on the right track here? Feels like I'm taking shots in the dark at an elephant in a broom closet and still missing...

Answer (score 0):

I use Ember-Model with built-in RESTAdapter, but should be compatible with your adapter:

```
// to add a post
var post = App.Post.create() // assuming your App.Post is your model class
// to add a comment inside it
var comment = post.get('comments').create()
```

To save, I use

```
post.save()
```

Since I am embedding the comments inside the post. If you're not, try call save() on comment object you've created:

```
comment.save()
post.save()
```

Comment: I've been successful creating child records, embedded, with static content thus far.  I've been trying to find or load an existing Post to add comments to, but falling short.

Answer (score 0):

try this

in the post controller when you save the record use this

```
post.save().then(function(post)     {self.transitionToRoute('comment.create', record);});
```

then in comments controller

```
 var post = this.get('comment').create();
```